# Strange duplicate Chrome icon with a display icon within in just popped up

Tags: macos, google-chrome, dock

This is on the latest version of OSX:

[image]

I have never seen this separate dock before, and I don't know if it's something native to OS X, Chrome, or maybe something else (Parallels perhaps)?

It has not right click context menu and I cannot drag it.

This is on a new MBP.

Any ideas?

EDIT: My wife has a macbook as well, and she is seeing one for Safari. Oddly enough, when I clicked on the icon a couple times, one of the tabs my wife had open popped up on my computer. What is this I don't even.

EDIT 2: It only pops up when both of our bluetooth is on and we're next to eachother, even though we have not chosen to Pair with eachothers computer.

This leaves me with more questions than answers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a feature called Handoff, which is part of [**Continuity**](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT6337). It allows you to access apps running on your other devices with the aim of letting you start a task on one device and resume it on another.

On your MacBook Pro, you are seeing a copy of Chrome running on another Mac which is on the same Wi-Fi network, where Bluetooth is enabled on both devices and you are signed in to both devices using the same iCloud account.

It can be turned off by following the instructions in the article linked above.